# Are there alternatives to the Google Places API, for lat/long retrieval?

Tags: database, latitude-longitude, software-recommendations, google-places-api

I am looking for an alternative API to Google places both free and paid to extract location data (lat/long) for business locations i.e all of the "coffee shops in London".

I have looked at Factual, OSM and POIPlaza. They do not fit because of different reasons varying from pricing to completeness of data.

Anything suitable out there?

Answer (score 2):

OpenStreetMaps has an API called nominatim. If you like you can access it via a python library called geopy.

You can pass a POI in the query. Take a look at this list for available POIs:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Special_Phrases/EN

Comment: The data in OSM is incomplete, also this API does not allow search for brand names directly.

Answer (score 1):

Geocoding API from mapbox [Geocoding Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/geocoding/) for address or [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim)

Comment: The Geocoding API does not allow you to search for a query such as "Starbucks" - unless I have missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Geocoding is only about streets. Its question, are complete data in Google Maps? Completeness of data in OSM depends on area of interest.

It is also possible to try [Bing REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx). I don't know details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Sygic Travel API](https://travel.sygic.com/b2b) for that. It provides global POI data with emphasis on the places relevant for travellers (such as attractions, coffee bars, restaurants, museums etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck using the Yahoo Placefinder API if you're comfortable using a little python; this link may be helpful to anyone looking > https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/providers/Yahoo.html